# Speeding deployment process in SAP Commerce Cloud

Tags: performance, deployment, sap-commerce-cloud

We have a SAP Commerce Cloud solution (SAP commerce ver. 2105.8) with Spartacus storefront

We create builds and deployments over SAP Commerce Cloud portal.

Can we decrease deployment time? Can we somehow influence this deployment process?

Thank you for your reply

Best regards

Patrik

We currently use the recreate mode and migration data setting when deploying

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is the fastest:

- Platform Update Mode: No migration required

> Database isn’t updated and no data is imported.

- Deployment Mode: Recreate (fastest, with downtime)

> Shuts down the running deployment and creates a new one based on a
> selected build.
>
> This operation is the fastest way to deploy the build, but it requires
> site downtime. If a problem occurs during the deployment, this option
> is also safer in terms of rollback potential.
>
> Visitors to your storefront see a temporary maintenance page until the
> deploy action completes.

For official documentation, see: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/0fa6bcf4736c46f78c248512391eb467/16a4fd7c4fee4bcc8b18e96b016e9faf.html?version=v2205

Comment: currently, we most often use this setting during deployment on production environment: migrate data and recreate the deployment mode, but still the deployment process takes approximately 40 minutes on production environment (from 20 min to 60 min, mostly >30 min ).

Comment: Do we have to recreate all services,pods (API-4 replicas, background processing-4 replicas, Backoffice-4 replicas, JS Storefront-3 replicas, Storefront-6replicas) if we make a change only to spartacus storefront?. This increases the time of the deployment process and there is a longer downtime of the site. Can we somehow optimize the deployment process if mostly changes are made only to the spartacus storefront? (backend is unchanged)

Comment: @PatrikLojan Currently, it's not possible to deploy only the Storefront. Both Backend and Frontend are built and deployed. I know know if SAP has a plan to suppport this "feature request", but I agree this is nice to have, especially if you have frontend changes only.